# In an isosceles triangle, the base and and the sides are equal to 5 and 20cm respectively. Find the angle bisector at the base of the triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

> In an isosceles triangle, the base and and the sides are equal to 5 and 20cm respectively. Find the angle bisector at the base of the triangle.

I think by finding the angle bisector, it means to find the length of the bisector. Maybe I'm wrong? Somebody help.... Thanks.

My attempt at answering : Isosceles triangle has the same sides, so 20cm each. Calculating the angle bisector is just like calculating the height in this case, so $\sqrt(20^2-2.5^2)$ that will give 19.8.

Comment: use Pythagoras.

Comment: Used it. Didn't get the right answer. @almagest

Comment: So (1) what is the right answer, (2) what answer did you get?

Comment: @ThermalRaindrops62: Show your work, and someone may be able to identify your mistake. (Generally, the more work you can show, the better. This information can help answerers to tailor their responses to best serve you, and to avoid wasting time telling you things you already know or talking over your head. (And it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.))

Comment: The right answer is 6cm, I got 19.8cm. @almagest

Comment: Noted @Blue. Tq

Comment: I'm guessing that it means the angle bisector of one of the angles that touches the base. I haven't worked out the math, but it should be about 6.
You'll probably need the law of sines/cosines, or something like that

Comment: Incidentally, 19.8 is not a very good approximation to the value of $\sqrt{20^2-(5/2)^2}$. To three digits, it’s close to 20.2.

Comment: I would never come to idea that "find the angle bisector" means "find the length of a line segment".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Given triangle $ABC$ with the side lengths $a,b$ and $c$,
the length of the bisector is given by
\begin{align} 
|AA_b|&=
\sqrt{bc\Big(1-\frac{a^2}{(b+c)^2}\Big)}
.
\end{align}

For $b=a=20,\ c=5$ it is therefore

\begin{align} 
|AA_b|&=
\sqrt{ac\Big(1-\frac{a^2}{(a+c)^2}\Big)}
=\sqrt{36}=6
.
\end{align}